# nested SELECT query in Sequelize

Tags: nested, subquery, sequelize.js

How do I make a query with a nested SELECT statement protected from sql injection in Sequelize?

An example of a conditional query for MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM cities WHERE country_id IN (SELECT id FROM countries WHERE lang = 'French');
```

Comment: Do you want to use Sequelize models with such nested SELECT or just a raw query?

Comment: @Anatoly, preferably with nested SELECT.  Raw queries are not protected from SQL-injections.

Comment: If using `bind` option all should be good with raw queries. Just don't try to insert a pieces of text manually and that's all

Comment: @Anatoly, would really appreciate it if you could convert the example.  because I don't completely understand what this is about

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QueryGenerator.selectQuery () saves from sql injections:

```
const lang = 'French';
const subQuery = sequelize.dialect.QueryGenerator.selectQuery('countries',
    {
        attributes: ['id'],
        where: {
             lang: lang,
        }
    })
    .slice(0,-1); // to remove the ';' from the end of the SQL

CitiesModel.findAll( {
    where: {
        country_id: {
            [Op.in]: sequelize.literal('(' + subQuery + ')'),
        }
    } 
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a raw query then you usually do not need to manually insert inputs to SQL:

```js
const res = sequelize.query(`SELECT * FROM cities 
  WHERE country_id IN (SELECT id FROM countries WHERE lang = $lang)`, {
  type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT,
  bind: {
        lang: 'French'
      });
```